# Seaborn doesn't show cumulative distributions

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In older projects I got the following results:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 5), sharex=True)
sns.distplot(df['Ratio(%)'].dropna(), bins=50, ax=axes[0])
sns.kdeplot(df['Ratio(%)'].dropna(), cumulative=True, ax=axes[1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

The version of the software was as follows:

- Python 3.7.1 64bit [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
- IPython 7.2.0
- OS Windows 10 10.0.17763 SP0
- matplotlib 3.0.2
- pandas 0.23.4
- seaborn 0.9.0

Now, doing the same, I get this error:

```
----> 1 sns.kdeplot(df['Ratio(%)'].dropna(), cumulative=True, ax=axes[1])   
ImportError: Cumulative distributions are currently only implemented in statsmodels. Please install statsmodels.
```

The version of the software is:

- Python 3.7.6 64bit [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
- IPython 7.11.1
- OS Windows 10 10.0.18362 SP0
- matplotlib 3.1.1
- pandas 0.25.3
- seaborn 0.10.0

But if I change the code:

```
sns.kdeplot(df['Ratio(%)'].dropna(), cumulative=False, ax=axes[1])
```

[image]

It works, but not the graphic I expect.

Comment: Have you tried to install `statsmodels`?

Comment: Yes, but no idea how to get started. `seaborn.kdeplot()` shall work, but fails with `cumulative=True`.

Comment: If the error is still `ImportError: Cumulative distributions are currently only implemented in statsmodels. Please install statsmodels.` it is very probable that you had some problem installing the library. Can you import it using `import statmodels`? Or you get an `ImportError`?

Comment: Yeah, it works! I don't know why, but adding `import statsmodels` works.